# R - using select_if() over a list of dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have a [list of data frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksWpG.png) `dfs` that I want to apply a `select_if()` function to filter within each data frame for columns that contain observations with a certain string pattern - `"pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)"`.

The function `select_if(~ any(.x == c("pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)")))` works exactly how I want it to when applied to individual list elements -

`ala |> select_if(~ any(.x == c("pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)")))`

but when selected through the list as below:

`dfs['ala']`

I am thrown several ambiguous list errors. I have tried a few different ways:

Using lapply(dfs, select_if()):

`cleaned <- lapply(dfs,select_if(~ any(.x == c("pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)"))))`

and a for loop:

`for(i in seq_along(dfs)){dfs[i] <- dfs[i] |> select_if(~ any(.x == c("pH","Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)")))`

But I keep running into variations of the error:
`Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "list"`

How can I do this without assigning each list element separately?

Comment: you can't use the `~`/`.` way of creating an anonymous function in lapply, use `function(x)` instead like `function(x) x %>% select_if(~ any(.x == c("pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)")))`

Comment: You need to use `[[` to extract a single item from a list. `dfs['ala']` is a 1-element list containing a data frame. `dfs[['ala']]` is just the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` needs its second argument to be a function. If you wanted the mean of each item of `x` you would use `lapply(x, mean)` or even `lapply(x, function(z) mean(z))`. You couldn't use `lapply(x, mean(z))` because while `mean` is a function, `mean(z)` is not.

Just the same, `lapply(dfs, select_if(~ any(.x == c("pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)"))))` fails because `select_if(~ any(.x, ...))` is not a function.

Also, `select_if` is being deprecated/superseded. The new preferred way is to use select helpers like `where()`. In your case, we would use (for a single data frame)

```
ala |> select(where(\(x) any(c("pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)") %in% x)))
```

For the list, we can use `lapply`'s `...` to pass the `where` through to `select`:

```
vals = c("pH", "Deep Rock", "Affinity (tot)")
cleaned = dfs |>
  lapply(
    select,
    where(\(x) any(vals %in% x))
  )
```